# Use PACKAGE_VERSION in the argument of AC_OUTPUT()

Tags: makefile, gnu, autotools, autoconf, automake

I apologize in advance for my lack of experience with m4sh.

I have a `configure.ac` file containing the following lines:

```m4
AC_INIT([libhelloworld], [2.5])

...

AC_OUTPUT([
Makefile
src/helloworld-${PACKAGE_VERSION}.pc
src/Makefile
])
```

The reason behind the argument of `AC_OUTPUT()` is that I would like to avoid to copy and paste the new version of my program in multiple places on every update. Therefore I decided to exploit the `PACKAGE_VERSION` macro, automatically defined when invoking `AC_INIT()` at the beginning of `configure.ac`.

The line `src/helloworld-${PACKAGE_VERSION}.pc` then correctly expands into `src/helloworld-2.5.pc` and everything seems to be working fine. However I have a couple of questions.

1. I use `${PACKAGE_VERSION}` as a shell variable, but `PACKAGE_VERSION` itself is a m4 macro. Can I trust that this will always work? Will it always be defined as such when `AC_OUTPUT()` is invoked?
2. Are there other ways of obtaining the value of `PACKAGE_VERSION` within `configure.ac`? For example, if instead of `configure.ac` I were inside `Makefile.am` I would not use the curly brackets, but the command evaluation syntax instead, as in `$(PACKAGE_VERSION)`. What is the *proper correct way* of doing what I want within `configure.ac`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `AC_INIT` states that `PACKAGE_VERSION` is an "output variable", meaning when you call `AC_INIT`, something like this gets executed:

```
AC_SUBST([PACKAGE_VERSION], [2.5])
```

This allows the configuration of input files such as `Makefile.in` (generated from `Makefile.am`) to rely on `@PACKAGE_VERSION@` inside those files being replaced by `2.5`.

There's nothing wrong with your approach if it works, but you might consider using `AS_VAR_SET([hello_version], [AC_PACKAGE_VERSION])` to set the `hello_version` shell variable and `src/helloworld-${hello_version}.pc` in Autoconf input.  This way, even if Autoconf no longer exposes a `PACKAGE_VERSION` shell variable in some future release, your code won't break because you'll be relying upon your own `hello_version` variable.

---

As an aside, it's a bit irregular to use `helloworld-2.5.pc` when the `helloworld` version is 1.0 or greater (i.e. the API is stable).  It's common to see `helloworld.pc`, except then there's the problem of what happens when you release 3.0 and replace the installed 2.x version of `helloworld.pc` with the 3.0 version: assuming you're using semantic versioning, 3.0 is incompatible with 2.x, and any code relying on something like `pkg-config --libs helloworld` will break.

You might then consider using `helloworld-2.pc` instead and when you release 3.0, you'd instead have `helloworld-3.pc` to avoid users of your library linking the incorrect/incompatible library (and also allowing users the option of moving to the new version at their own pace); one can also apply this idea in Automake for a version-specific header directory:

```
## SOURCE PATH     => INSTALL PATH
## include/hello.h => $(includedir)/helloworld-2/hello.h
helloincludedir = @includedir@/helloworld-@hello_major@
helloinclude_HEADERS = include/hello.h
```

Autoconf also allows you to specify an output file's inputs, so an output file `src/helloworld-${hello_major}.pc` in the build directory could be generated from `src/helloworld.pc.in` in the source directory without you needing to update the `src/helloworld.pc.in` filename when moving from 2.x to 3.0; this could also be used with `AC_INIT` if you're OK with macros, allowing you to control the version info in one central location:

```
m4_define([hello_version_major], [2]) dnl
m4_define([hello_version_minor], [5]) dnl
m4_define([hello_version], [hello_version_major[.]hello_version_minor]) dnl
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([libhelloworld], [hello_version])
AS_VAR_SET([hello_major], [hello_version_major])
AS_VAR_SET([hello_minor], [hello_version_minor])
# For automake and configuration of pkg-config file
AC_SUBST([hello_major])
AC_SUBST([hello_minor])
AC_SUBST([hello_version])
...
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
    Makefile
    src/Makefile
    src/helloworld-]hello_version_major[.pc:src/helloworld.pc.in
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

I realize it looks surprisingly more complicated than one might expect, but that's Autoconf for you.  Note that I had to use some odd quoting in `AC_CONFIG_FILES` to make use of the macro.  Using

```
src/helloworld-${hello_major}.pc:src/helloworld.pc.in
```

instead of the macro resulted in a crippled `config.status` file being generated in Autoconf 2.69 (try `config.status` with no arguments, then `config.status src/helloworld-2.pc` to see the issue); I haven't tested any other versions.  I've reported the bug, but the macro works until the next release.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! Just for completeness, I think that with the same *odd quoting* in `AC_OUTPUT()` it should be possible to directly use `AC_PACKAGE_VERSION` (instead of my previous `${PACKAGE_VERSION}`). As for the naming conventions regarding `helloworld-XX.pc`, thank you again for the explanation. I will make a bit of research around.